# StackExchange.Redis ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect() Intermittently Works

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve, stackexchange.redis

I am using `StackExchange.Redis` to talk to 3 different Redis instances: 1 on the same subnet and 2 remotely. Here's my configuration code:

```
var configurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    EndPoints =
    {
        { host, port }
    },
    KeepAlive = 180,
    Password = password,
    DefaultVersion = new Version("2.8.5"),
    // Needed for cache clear
    AllowAdmin = true
};

var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configurationOptions );
```

the last line throws a connection exception approximately 70% of the time:

> It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail

Why is this intermittent and/or what am I doing wrong? When I ping the Redis server in a command prompt, there is 0% packet loss and a <1 ms response. The network is stable.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is what the log outputs when it fails:

```
10.48.68.28:6379,keepAlive=180,version=2.8.5

1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from 10.48.68.28:6379 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 00:00:01 to respond...
10.48.68.28:6379 did not respond
10.48.68.28:6379 failed to nominate (WaitingForActivation)
No masters detected
10.48.68.28:6379: Standalone v2.8.5, master; keep-alive: 00:03:00; int: Connecting; sub: ConnectedEstablished, 1 active; not in use: DidNotRespond
10.48.68.28:6379: int ops=0, qu=4, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=1; sub ops=2, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, subs=1, sync=2, socks=1
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0+2=2 (0.20 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
Starting heartbeat...
```

Comment: If you pass in a TextWriter as the log parameter (StringWriter works fine) - what does it say?

Comment: LSO: is this right at first startup? First time? I'm wondering how much is JIT / Fusion / DNS / etc

Comment: Right at startup, first time. When I expand the sync timeout to 30000ms it doesn't help. Always waits the max and fails. Trying `BookSleeve` right now to see if it works.

Comment: Curious. Very curious. Question: are you specifying an ip? Or a host name?

Comment: IP for 1 of the instances, hostname for the other 2. I am trying the log now and will report back in a sec. Also a given process will only be configured for 1 of the 3 instances (think DEV, QA, PROD)

Comment: AHA! Got it to fail again, stand by for log.

Comment: the qu=4 is **very** interesting to me - it suggests the writer didn't start. Can you tell me what version you are using exactly? Basically qu is the unsent queue: there are 4 messages that for some reason have not yet been sent. This troubles me.

Comment: The fact that it is connecting rather than connection established also intriguing

Comment: @MarcGravell running [latest nuget package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis) 1.0.270

Comment: @MarcGravell if I can help by testing in any way, let me know. Happy to do so. Just wanna make it work. :)

Comment: long weekend here: I'll have to look when i can. Does increasing the connect timeout help?

Comment: Nope, if I increase the timeout to 60 seconds, it takes 60 seconds to fail. Which would be in line with your "it isn't sending because it's queued" thing. Enjoy the long weekend! We shall reconvene next week. :)

Comment: Did you manage to work this out?

Comment: @Craig to the best of my knowledge, Marc is still looking into it. If there's a new version you could try upgrading to it. I went back to BookSleeve for the time being and it worked well.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to work around it by setting a `ConnectTimeout` on the client when connecting to Redis.
Here was my code

```
 ConnectionMultiplexer connection = 
        ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("endpoint,password=password,ConnectTimeout=10000");
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a somewhat common issue: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/42

I just downloaded the new build and haven't seen the problem again. Yet.

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting is usually a sign that you have not set `abortConnect=false` in your connection string. The default value for `abortConnect` is `true`, which makes it so that `StackExchange.Redis` won't reconnect to the server automatically under some conditions. We strongly recommend that you set `abortConnect=false` in your connection string so that Redis will auto-reconnect in the background if a network blip occurs.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30918632/2236811

So my `init()` looked like this

```
ConfigurationOptions co = new ConfigurationOptions()
{
    SyncTimeout = 500000,
    EndPoints =
    {
        {url,portNumber }
    },
    AbortOnConnectFail = false // this prevents that error
};

seClient = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(co);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For me this error was because total number of connection reached to its max limit i.e. 10K. Restarting Client and kill some of them solved the problem. You can check Azure portal and figure out if you have reached max limit for any of the resources.