# It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer

Tags: c#, azure, azure-redis-cache

I have the following piece of code to connect to azure redis cache.

```
public class CacheConnectionHelper
{
    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(SettingsHelper.AzureRedisCache);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it this way

```
public static List<Models.Module> GetModules()
{
    IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
    List<Models.Module> listOfModules = new List<Models.Module>();        
    listOfModules = (List<Models.Module>)cache.Get("ApplicationModules");
    if (listOfModules == null)
    {
        listOfModules = dbApp.Modulos.ToList();
        cache.Set("ApplicationModules", listOfModules, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SettingsHelper.CacheModuleNames));
        return listOfModules;
    }
    else {
        return listOfModules;
    }
}
```

However 1 or 2 times per day I get this exception:

> Additional information: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING

The question is how can I refactor this code to go to the database in case the cache connection fails?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The error you are getting is usually a sign that you have not set **abortConnect=false** in your connection string.  The default value for *abortConnect* is *true*, which makes it so that *StackExchange.Redis* won't reconnect to the server automatically under some conditions.  We strongly recommend that you set *abortConnect=false* in your connection string so that *SE.Redis* will auto-reconnect in the background if a network blip occurs.

Comment: thanks , this connection string worked for me 172.17.0.2:12000,abortConnect=false

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Too bad the default setting is `true`.

Comment: It may also be necessary to increase the default timeouts, e.g. `"Redis": "localhost,abortConnect=false,connectTimeout=30000,responseTimeout=30000"`

Answer (score 22):

For beginners who dive in other's code an face this problem:

```
if (RedisConn == null)
{ 
    ConfigurationOptions option = new ConfigurationOptions
    {
        AbortOnConnectFail = false,
        EndPoints = { redisEndpoint }
    };
    RedisConn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(option);
}
```

Comment: Perfect... but what is the failsafe? If it fails on the first network blip we are ok with letting it try again but not indefinitely. Are there additional options? Google pointed me here.

Comment: Found it, it's a ConfigurationOption of ConnectRetry set to the number of retries. Not sure what the default is set to.

Comment: Default is 3 for ConnectRetry -
 https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html

Answer (score 6):

You should also pay attention to the last part of your error message, as it seems to provide very useful details about the reason why connection have failed.

In your case:

It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. **UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING**

My case:

It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. **Timeout**

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by changing:

```
CacheSettings:ConnectionString=basketdb:6379
```

to

```
CacheSettings__ConnectionString=basketdb:6379
```

in the *docker-compose.override.yml*

Answer (score 2):

For those maintaining older codebases, you may run into "It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); to create a disconnected multiplexer, disable AbortOnConnectFail. UnableToResolvePhysicalConnection on PING"

Once I upgraded to a more recent nuget package the error was still present but I got more error information: "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm".

Once I applied the registry keys mentioned [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/596) I was ok.  For those that don't wish to make that global change I believe there has been a [PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/pull/603) for a setting.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved in a new release, the version 1.2.6 - you can see in [Here](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/513)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by changing my connection string from localhost:6379 to 127.0.0.1:6379

Answer (score 0):

For me, the connection string was incorrect. Adding the correct connection string details worked with stackexchange.redis 2.1.58

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way.

```
public class RedisService
{
    private readonly string _host;
    private readonly int _port;
    private ConnectionMultiplexer _connectionMultiplexer;

    public RedisService(string host, int port)
    {
        _host = host;
        _port = port;
    }

    public void Connect() => _connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect($"{_host}:{_port}");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do ensure that you already have Redis set up. Here are instructions links for the respective OS:

Mac OS: https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/1b8a321e7c58499ef9f9441b2faa0aa8

Windows: https://dev.to/divshekhar/how-to-install-redis-on-windows-10-3e99